# how to automatically create an interface member from within a class using Resharper?

Tags: resharper

I have already created an interface, and I am in the class that binds to the interface.

If I create a new method in the concret class, is there a shortcut to create the method declaration in the interface?

Answer (score 4):

Refactor - [Pull Members Up](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/help20/Refactoring/pullMembersUp.html):

> This refactoring helps you move type members to a superclass or an interface. This operation is useful as a way to generalize behavior. ReSharper analyzes all members in the current class and makes a list of members that you can pull up. Before completing the refactoring, ReSharper also checks for possible conflicts, for example, whether the members that you are trying to move to a superclass will be accessible in the destination type. The reverse functionality is available with 'Push Members Down'.

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard shortcut for invoking this re-factoring is: Alt+R > R > U